# ASP.NET Core - Can I authorize Azure AD Users within my app without accessing the Azure AD?

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, authorization

Let me preface this by saying I'm extremely new to ASP.Net.

I have developed a basic app displaying company data (by department), and providing CRUD functionality for specific users. Obviously this means an Authorization attribute is required, as users shouldn't be able to view data of other departments, and only department managers can create, update and delete records.

The app uses Azure AD Authentication. However, I have no access to the Azure AD of our company. Therefore, I'm not able to register my app and assign Roles to users. Instead, is there any way to accomplish this "within my app", i.e. through code? Something like:

```
bool isAuthorized (string user) {
    if (user.Equals("user@company.com") {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

All the guides so far I've gone through either assume you have access to the Azure AD, or manage the user database yourself, so I've had no luck with them.

I will request access to the Azure AD if I have to, I just want to make sure there's no other way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an app to authenticate a user against Azure AD, it *needs* an app registration that gives it its client id.

Purely technically speaking you *could* use the client id of another app etc., but that would be limited in its scenarios and a really bad practice!

Comment: Thanks, exactly the answer I was looking for.